# Can 'sbt' accomplish 'makefile'-like functionality

Tags: scala, makefile, sbt

I'm a new scala/sbt user with a ton of experience in writing Makefiles. In GNU make, I could write a file like:

```
c.txt: a.txt b.txt
       cat a.txt b.txt > $@
```

The result of that is that, when I run make, `c.txt` is recreated if either `a.txt` or `b.txt` is *newer* than any existing `c.txt` (`$@` is a mnemonic that represents the name of the current target). If there exists a `c.txt` which is newer than `a.txt` and `b.txt`, then no execution happens.

I have some build steps in my project that are going to be derived from non-scala/java methoodologies, and thus need some make-type dependencies. My expectation would be that 'sbt' can easily do this, since it's a build system that's like 40 years newer than 'make'. But I see nothing clearly articulating this case in the docs.

Could someone provide some examples?

Comment: I suspect that part of the reason you haven't got a response yet is that your question is quite general.  I'm tempted to answer it, but if you could narrow it down, you're more likely to get a response.  The short answer is, yes it can be made to do what you want, but it's not the most natural way to think about it.   If you have a "standard layout", there's an easier way to go.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow -- the question quite intentionally is written to ask for an answer that would make sense to somebody who's uses make for all sorts of purposes. But I suppose an answer that focused on how to automate C builds (i.e. inferred .o dependencies from .c, and a link step based on the .o files, within sbt would probably get me going in the right direction)

Answer (score 2):

This should provide something like what you're asking for.

Here's a simple sbt project, consisting of two files with the following layout:

```
myproject/build.sbt
myproject/src/main/scala/org/foo/Hello.scala
```

The build file contains:

```
name          := "hello"
version       := "0.01"
organization  := "org.foo"
scalaVersion  := "2.12.4"
```

The scala source file contains:

```
package org.foo

object Hello extends App {
  println("Hello")
}
```

Among the predefined sbt tasks is "compile".  Issuing the command line "sbt compile" for the first time results in the generation of various files below the "target" directory (most of which you aren't typically concerned with).

Among them are the following:

```
./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello$.class
./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello$delayedInit$body.class
./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello.class
```

The compile task actions in this example are somewhat similar to what you would get from the following makefile:

```
all: ./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo ./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello.class

./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo:
    mkdir -p ./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo

./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello.class:
    scalac -d ./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo src/main/scala/org/foo/Hello.scala
```

Issuing the command line "make all" would result in the same three files being generated:

```
./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello$.class
./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello$delayedInit$body.class
./target/scala-2.12/classes/org/foo/Hello.class
```

In either case, you would be able to call the main method in the Hello class with the following command line:

```
$ scala -cp target/scala-2.12/classes org.foo.Hello
Hello
```

The "sbt compile" task would also generate 35 other files below the target directory, and in addition it would generate 58 files below the "project" directory, so the comparison is simplistic.

You can list predefined tasks with the following command line:

sbt tasks

On my system (sbt 1.1.2), this prints a list with 32 entries, with descriptions.

If instead of the "compile" task we had issued the "package" task, it would have automatically triggered the "compile" task ("package" depends on "compile" by default) and in addition would have generated a jar file containing the generated .class files:

```
$ jar -tf target/scala-2.12/hello_2.12-0.01.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
org/
org/foo/
org/foo/Hello$.class
org/foo/Hello$delayedInit$body.class
org/foo/Hello.class
```

In general, a build definition accomplishes more with less verbosity than an equivalent makefile, especially if your project relies on default assumptions.

Comment: Update: there's a new sbt plugin that might be of interest to anyone who prefers the makefile concept:  https://www.ethanatkins.com/2019/09/11/introducing-sbt-make.html